# Clearing a named range with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, button, named-ranges

I have two button objects in an old worksheet that have worked just fine for years.  The goal is to have two named ranges and to clear them with two separate buttons.  Both ranges have merged cells in them.

I can't seem to get Button3 working in the new worksheet.

Button1 works just fine:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

'Loop through Named Range, clearing contents
For Each m_cell In Range("Clear1stList")
    m_cell.MergeArea.ClearContents
    Next

End Sub
```

Button3 code is almost identical but doesn't work at all.  It always ends in Error 400.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

'Loop through Named Range, clearing contents
For Each m_cell In Range("ClearDailyLog")
    m_cell.MergeArea.ClearContents
    Next

End Sub
```

Button3 always breaks at m_cell.MergeArea.ClearContents
I have deleted the entire named range "ClearDailyLog"and set it over again to no avail.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  It turns out the previous worksheet had this code written under it's own module.  This time I was trying to clear named ranges on a different sheet than the one the buttons were on.